# trying to understand permutation generation

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, permutation, backtracking

I am trying to understand a permutation algorithm given [here](https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/generating-permutations-of-all-elements-of-an-arra/)
what I am not clear is with first block of pseudo code where they mention

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
function permutation(start, end):
#i will go from start to end
    for i -> (start, end+1):
        permutation(start+1,end)
```

why has end+1 used in for i loop this is not clear to me as far as I understand end+1 should go out of index of array to which permutation has to be applied, but this is not the case here this is what I am not clear with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is familiar in Python, and uses the same (unfortunate) idiom in the pseudo code. In Python, the start of a range is *inclusive*, while the end is *exclusive*. Later on that page the Python code excerpt proves that that indeed is the case:

```
for i in range(start, end+1):
```

With this code `i` will be sequentially assigned all integers from `start` to `end` inclusive, but excluding the `end + 1`.

In C one would often use `<` in loops - then it would happen there too:

```
for (size_t i = start; start < end + 1; start++)
                               ^^^^^^^
```

though more natural would be to write

```
for (size_t i = start; start <= end; start++)
```

Comment: What would be more natural in either language would be to fix the definition of `permutation` so that it uses half-open ranges. In the Python version, it would also be cool to avoid depending on a global.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i -> (start, end+1)
```

It means iterate for every value beginning from **start**, with auto-increment and condition satisfying **end+1**

```
permutation(start+1,end)
```

It is just the same function call with parameters having values of start and end passed into it

e.g

```
function permutation(start, end)
```

with start = 1 and end = 10

Inside foreach will iterate starting from 1 with auto-increment till it reaches 10, means less that (10+1) = 11

Then, permutation(start+1,end) is called
Let's say for the first item start = 1. It will call with start as 2 and end as 10